# Как сделать переключение видео?

Tags: javascript

Не прошу кода, а всего лишь пояснение
Как на html/js сделать такую штуку, имеется 3 видео и 1 кнопка, при нажатии на кнопку должен меняться ролик с 1 по 3, то есть у нас 1 видео, нажали на кнопку стало 2 и т.д и чтобы после 3 видео, шло опять 1, именно при нажатии на кнопку, а не по окончанию видео
Я так предполагаю, что можно проверять аттрибут ссылки к видео, если он равен 1 видео, то меняем на 2 и т.д, но может это можно как то проще сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Никакие ссылки проверять не нужно.

Логика обычно пишется в коде, а потом эта логика проецируется на UI.

Можно хранить имена видео в массиве. А также иметь переменную - счётчик. При клике на кнопку - нужно брать номер счётчитка, затем из массива по этому этому самому индексу брать имя видео, вставлять в плеер, запускать play и прибавлять счётчик, чтобы в следующий раз взялось следующее видео.

Ну и не забыть проверку, что если индекс видео больше чем длина массива, то сбрасывать индекс (счётчик) на первоначальное значение

Comment: "Ну и не забыть проверку" - а можно и без него :)

Comment: @EzioMercer я думаю все эти приколы с делением по модулю - это не для текущего уровня знаний человека)

Comment: Ты умён, спору нет;
Но математика всех точнее,
Всех логичней и яснее. (c) ChatGPT